# Remove all session except 1 Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

,Hi all,

I am trying to delete all sessions except UserId session.

I only want to keep Session["UserId"] other sessions remove

There is something ı can use for this purpose in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var UserId = Session["UserId"];
Session.Clear();
Session["UserId"] = UserId;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is nothing like it , so you have to remove all session by their respected names and keep userid session